# android menu vs android tab bar

Tags: android, menu, tabbar

What would be better to integrate in the application- all options (for new screens) in menu, customized for each screen or have it on top of screen as tab bar- squishing the screen? what do normal android users prefer using? and from design perspective is it okay to keep changing items in menu bar in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a combination.
Different Views into your app data can go as Tabs.
Quick actions like search can be ActionViews.

You can also show different tabs depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but for future generations:
In my case, it was the task to replicate an existing iOS app with iOS UITabBar, so playing with the bottom-navigation Android pattern I found that it is much easier to use `FragmentContainerView`s than the official bottom-navigation pattern from the Android Architecture repository. Check the repository, there's a test application that you can run to check if the solution matches your expectations: https://github.com/Codeveyor/Android-Tab-Bar